# Angular 11: Refused to apply style from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported

Tags: angular, angular11

I am facing an issue with my angular project first time it will work fine but after refresh the page the error comes. Here is my code:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "rfs": "^9.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
 "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          },
```

Main Routing

```
{path : '', component : LoginComponent},
  { 
    path : 'user' , component: AfterLoginComponent,
    children:[{path: '',loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule)}]
  },
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running it with 'ng serve'?  It looks like your web server is serving your CSS file with the wrong mime type.

Comment: Yes I am running it with 'ng serve' and it not showing any error at first time but when I change anything in code then the page refresh as usual ... then its show this error

Comment: are you sure it's "src/styles.scss" ? try "src/styles.css"

Comment: If i change this then it show this error at compile time An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'H:\angular-web\real-state\associate\src\styles.css'
See "C:\Users\dodo\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-kBbjp2\angular-errors.log" for further details.
I have chosen the scss option at the time of project installation.

Comment: then it should be "styles.css" only

Comment: you can also import your bootstrap styles in your styles.scss
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: @user733421 "then it should be "styles.css" only" what its means ... if i change styles.scss to styles.css then it throw an error at serving time the error is mention above comment.

Comment: nevermind, I was wrong, try checking your base path. it seems weird that your code is asking for styles.css from  /users/ instead of just /

Comment: Did you [setup your project](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-structure-scss-in-an-angular-app-a1b8a759a028) to use scss (sass)?  Have you changed your base url?  It looks like it's looking for 'users/styles.css', which is probably served as your home page html as if it was a route to '/users' and not your style file...

Comment: @user733421 base path is set to "/"

Comment: Try adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to your first route, `''` might be catching other routes

Comment: @user733421 thank you so much dear, now no errors come.